# What is this type of idiomatic way to talk, or does it have a different name?

Tags: idioms, american-english

Sometimes my friend will say things with alternative words, like:

> Firefox literally sips memory

in that case they were trying to say Firefox doesn't use a lot of system resources, but it sounds much funnier. What is this way of talking called? Is it called idiomatic speech?

Comment: Slang, exaggeration, picturesque, creative, hip or pseudo-hip? A good example of using literally to mean figuratively. But *sips* is colorful.

Comment: Firefox uses a shite-ton of sys resources.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you looking for a positive or neutral term (colourful, poetic), rather than a negative one (flowery language, Gongorism). Do you consider "sips" to be a particularly fitting and accurate term, or one that's curious and whimsical and offbeat? Do you consider it wise or funny?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply a metaphor.  Its (purported) less intensive use is called "sipping", as intensive use might be called "gulping."  Both of which use the metaphor of drinking.

Comment: Yes, sipping versus gulping. Gold Star. :)

Answer (score -1):

**Witticism** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witticism)): (plural witticisms) a witty remark.

- **Witty**  ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witty)) meanings 3, 4, 5

1. (obsolete) Wise, having good judgement.
2. (archaic) Possessing a strong intellect or intellectual capacity; intelligent, skilful, ingenious.
3. Clever; amusingly ingenious.

   - His speech was both witty and informative.
4. Full of wit.

   - His frequent quips mark him as particularly witty.
5. Quick of mind; insightful; in possession of wits.

   - She may have grown older, but she has grown no less witty.